# How to invoke functions between two shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell

I have functions to `logInfo()/logError()` in a shell script (logger.sh). There are other shell scripts (example: createuser.sh) which require logging. How to invoke functions like logInfo() from createuser.sh

Without function invocations, these logInfo/logError functions are getting copied to every shell script that requires logging.

Comment: I believe you can add `source file_name.sh` to include the the functions in another script.

Comment: Note that it's appropriate to use an extension on shell *libraries*, such as the files you're sourcing. Shell *scripts* shouldn't have extensions more than any other executable does -- you don't run `ls.c` or `ls.elf`, you just run `ls`; similarly, when you install a Python program like `pip`, even though the modules it uses ends in `.py`, the entry point itself is just `pip` with no extension. See also [Commandname Extensions Considered Harmful](http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - should the shell scripts (that would call functions from shell libraries) have functions or should the shell scripts just have commands? What is the general/standard convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your logger functions in a separate file (that **only** contains functions, no commands), say myfuncs.sh.  Then in any other script that needs these functions, somewhere near the top of that script add a line:

```
. myfuncs.sh
```

or, equivalently:

```
source myfuncs.sh
```

The functions in myfuncs.sh will then be available in that script.

Comment: `.sh` if they're developed to run on any POSIX-compliant shell, `.bash` if they can used only by bash, `.ksh` if they can be used only by ksh, etc. Naming conventions are important here.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing in the logger.sh script is the functions (ie: nothing runsfid you execute it from the command line, then you can source the shell script  by including the line:

`. logger.sh`

See: https://ss64.com/bash/source.html